# how to insert line break to existing word paragraph using SyncFusion?

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I have seen  [this](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/working-with-paragraph#appending-breaks) documentation on adding paragraphs and inserting lien breaks while building the paragraph, but I can't do the same for existing paragraphs at a specific location.

Comment: Can you share at what stage you are working on the subject and what exactly the problem is? This way we can be of more help. There are multiple ways to put a line break in the text you are using, and they are syncfusion independent solutions. It would be more helpful to fully understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the given details, we have found your requirement is to insert a line break to existing paragraph in the Word document using Syncfusion DocIO library.

To achieve this, we suggest you to create a new instance of the line break and insert it into the existing paragraph at the specific location (index) as per your requirement. Please refer the below highlighted code snippets to achieve your requirement.

```
//Loads the template document.
WordDocument document = new WordDocument("Template.docx");
//Gets the text body of first section.
WTextBody textBody = document.Sections[0].Body;
//Gets the paragraph at index 1.
WParagraph paragraph = textBody.Paragraphs[1];
//Creates a new instance of the line break.
Break lineBreak = new Break(document, BreakType.LineBreak);
//Inserts line break to the paragraph at a specific location (index).
paragraph.ChildEntities.Insert(2, lineBreak);
document.Save(@"Output.docx");
document.Close();
```